TFS Shared Files
We are on TFS 2017 (Update 3) and have a series of old VB6 projects in there that we migrated from VSS last year. In VSS they were using some kind of link to share certain files between multiple project files. This was done so that if they changed the file in one project, those changes were replicated to the same file in all projects. Based on usage, this would not be an issue with a .NET project, as these would all just be in a shared library project.
Today one of those developers brought to my attention that changing the file in one of the projects did not change the shared version (which is expected). It seems that this type of linking is no longer supported (as of TFS2010). We are not really in a position to change all of these project files (the whole setup is very finnicky), so is there something I can do here besides tell everyone that when they make a change they have to change all of these files?
The folder structure is something like below, and any change to any copy of SharedFileX would be replicated to all copies of that file regardless of location.
-MainFolder
    -VBEXE
        -ProjectFolder1
            -SharedFile1
        -ProjectFolder2
            -SharedFile2
        -ProjectFolder3
            -SharedFile1
            -SharedFile2
    -VBSharedClasses
        -SharedFile1
        -SharedFile2


It's recommended to share a sample in the statement. Is it related to the project code management?

@wadezhou-MSFT it is not a statement, but I can edit in a sample of the folder structure.

Thanks @DaveJohnson. The folder structure is helpful but still not sure what changes need to do  when one of developers change the file. Could you please show a sample?

@wadezhou-MSFT Not sure how else to show a sample of that? When they change the file it should be changed everywhere because it's shared.

As per my understanding, because the link doesn't work on TFS2017, when any SharedFileX file is changed, you would like to replicate the change to other copies automatically, is it your expectation? If it is, you can use pipeline to monitor on the files to achieve this. Would add details after your confirmation.

@wadezhou-MSFT yes, that is what I would like to achieve

i shared the pipeline sample to automatically replicate the change to all same named files in the repository. If your file resides in different project, and different branch, it could be more complicated. But you can follow the sample for consideration.

@wadezhou-MSFT I did see that, but have not had a chance to attempt to implement. It makes sense though, so should be able to get it working, and will mark as answer when I do.


The folder structure is something like below, and any change to any copy of SharedFileX would be replicated to all copies of that file regardless of location.

To automatically replicate the change to all same named files regardless of location, you need:

Monitor on the change of SharedFile named files and trigger the pipeline.
Find the changed file path and its name.
With a loop to replicate the file to other same named files.
Push back the change to your devops repo.

The folder structure:

Below is a sample yaml pipeline which works in my project:
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - 'MainFolder/**/SharedFile*'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true        # keep the credential to push back the change to repo afterwards
  fetchDepth: 0                # fetch the history so that can get the changed files.

- powershell: |
      ## get the changed files
      $files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $(Build.SourceVersion))
      $temp=$files -split ' '
      $count=$temp.Length
      echo "Total changed $count files"
     
      For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
      {
        $file=$temp[$i]
        # filter SharedFile named file
        if ($file -like "*SharedFile*") {
         echo "this is file: $file"

         # Get the full path to the source file
         $sourceFile = Join-Path "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)" $file

         # Find all files in the repository that have the same name as the source file
         $targetFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)" -Filter $(Split-Path $file -Leaf) -Recurse

         foreach ($targetFile in $targetFiles) {
          # Check if the source file is the same as the target file
          if ($sourceFile -ne $targetFile.FullName) {
              # Copy the source file to the target file, overwriting it
              echo $targetFile
              Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $targetFile.FullName -Force
          }
        }
       }
      }

- script: |
    git config --global user.email "test@example.com"
    git config --global user.name "test Name"
    git add .
    git commit -m "Update shared files"
    git push origin HEAD:main
  displayName: 'Commit and push changes'

Once i change any SharedFileX file, it will replicate the change to all others.

I used build service account to push back the change, make sure the account has contribute permission on the repo.
Changed replicated to all same named files:

